# Google Maps: InfoWindow vs InfoBox vs InfoBubble

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobubble

[InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) is a standard part of the Google Maps API v3, allowing the user to create a pop-up window on a map, but there's also two other libraries that seem to do the same thing:

- [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox)
- [InfoBubble](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble)

I understand that these two most likely offer more customization options than the original InfoWindow, but are there any other differences? Are they competitors or do they do different jobs? Is one more up-to-date than the other?

Comment: You can loosely say that InfoBubble is a successor of InfoBox. They are both part of google maps utility library, while InfoBox is not being updated anymore, but they fill the same purpose.

Comment: The built in [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) is not very customizable.  If you want custom styling or behavior, you can use one of those third party libraries (or write your own).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While **InfoWindow** is the **built-in object** of the Google Maps JavaScript API, **InfoBox** and **InfoBubble** are **"third-party" objects** of the InfoWindow, which extend it. Because of this the two are located in the utility-library.

So they are doing the same job, but are more enhanced concerning customizations. The InfoBubble seems to be better documented and maintained. The InfoBox library is also not mentioned on the [Google Maps Github site](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html) anymore. So if you have to make the choice I would go for InfoBubble instead of InfoBox (if you need more options compared to the standard InfoWindow).